# How to store data receieved from UM7

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

dear,

i run a UM7 drivers but i'm not able to see inertial data (i'm able to see only messages like received packet XY without data or sending command zero gyroscopes).

Do you have some solution how to show inertial data (from accelerometers and gyroscopes?)

Thank you for your responce

---

Edit: thank you for your response. There is a manual how to show data for other users. I hope it should be useful.

1. install ROS + other features
2. sudo su
3. roscore
4. second terminal
5. sudo su
6. cd /root/catkin_ws   (or place where you have a catkin workspace)
7. source devel/setup.bash
8. rosrun um7 um7_driver _port:=/dev/ttyAMA0

A) show data in RVIZ

9. Third console
10. rosrun rviz rviz (you need rviz_imu_plugin)
11. add module IMU
12. fixed frame : imu_link
    13 in module IMU fill topic /imu/data
13. rviz should show data from IMU

B) show RAW data in console

9. third console
10. sudo su
11. rostopic echo /imu/data (or show another type using rostopic list)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253138/how-to-store-data-receieved-from-um7/) by [Wiew](https://answers.ros.org/users/29043/wiew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2017-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-21**:
Why are you running things in a `sudo su` session? That should not be necessary (and is often very much undesirable).

**Comment by [Wiew](https://answers.ros.org/users/29043/wiew/) on 2017-02-21**:
Yeah sure, it is not necessary for all users. In my case i installed ros under root and without sudo session i am not able to run ros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Visualising and storing it are two different things, but both should be possible.

For a live 3D visualisation of the data, you can use the [rviz_imu_plugin](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz_imu_plugin) in RViz.

For plotting the data, you could look at [rqt_plot](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_plot) or one of the alternatives that exist, like [rqt_multiplot](https://github.com/ethz-asl/rqt_multiplot_plugin) or [PlotJuggler](https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler).

For recording the data, take a look at [rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag). That will also allow you to play it back later.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3